# Is selector starting with ">" sign a proper way to find children in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I would like to find specific descendants of specific children of an element. I can do this:

```
$(element).children('.second').find('.third')
```

and apparently this works as well:

```
$(element).find('> .second .third')
```

I'd prefer the latter but I can't find documentation for selectors **starting with** '>' sign. [This piece of documentation](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) doesn't say anything about it.
My question is: is it safe to use the second one? Is it part of jQuery API?

Comment: you should use  `$(element).find('.second > .third')`

Answer (score 0):

*would like to find specific descendants of specific children of an element*

The selector is called **[immediate child selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)**. You need to use:

```
                 //vv SPECIFIC CHILDREN
$(element).find('.second > .third');
                         //^^DESCENDANTS
```

Comment: Thanks, but I linked to the same document in my question and explained why it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are equivalent. Basically `$(element).children('.myclass') == $(element).('> .myclass') == $(document).find(element > .myclass)`.

When you use a space inside a jQuery selector you mean match descendants.

For this reason, `$(element).find('> .second .third')` means "find the elements belonging to class `third` inside (at any level) the elements belonging class `second` which are direct children of element.

`$(element).children('.second').find('.third')` means the same thing.

Have a look at this structure

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="second">
        <div class="third"></div>
        <div class="third"></div>
        <div class="placeholder">
            <div class="third"></div>
            <div class="second">
                <div class="third"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the results of different selectors are as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Direct children (second)
    console.log("0: " + $('#parent').find('> .second').length) // 2
    //All children (second) + All children (third)
    console.log("1: " + $('#parent').children('.second').find('.third').length) // 4
    console.log("2: " + $('#parent').find('> .second .third').length) // 4
    //All children (second) + direct children (third)
    console.log("3: " + $('#parent').children('.second').find('> .third').length) // 2
    //Direct children (second) + direct children (third)
    console.log("3: " + $('#parent').find('> .second > .third').length) // 2
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/h3s454bq/

Comment: Thanks, I am aware that it works, but I can't find documentation for this. This doc (https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) does not answer my question.